# Passing multiple array values to a web api controller using a single model attribute

Tags: c#, sql, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a $scope object as bellow

```
$scope.array=[{"ID":"1","ID":"2","ID":"3"}];
```

What I want to do is pass these values to the following SQL query

```
Select * from table where ID in("Here I need the above 3 values one after another")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: any attempt in server side ?

Comment: That is the thing I want to know. Can I pass this array values using a List<> in the Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class

```
public class myId {
  public int ID {set;get;}
}
```

pass it to web api

```
public void submitID(List<myId> ids){
  // do rest of the things
  var id = string.Join(",", ids.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray());
  var query="Select * from table where ID in('"+id+"')";

}
```

Comment: If I'm using a model with multiple attributes 

`public class model{
public int ID {get;set;}

public int age{get;set;}
}`

how can I get the values?

Comment: this value have to in json object otherwise it won't pass. It will catch those which property mentioned both in class and json object @TharinduSenanayake